# Is it required to have a google notebook instance running for every user who needs a Jupyter notebook on AI platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-ai-platform

We are using Google AI platform. One of the requirement I have is as below

When a data scientist will need to do some EDA on a Dataset, he will send it to support team who will push it to GCS and create an external table on Bigquery and also create a notebook instance for the data scientist.

My question is , do we need to create a separate notebook instance for each data scientist. Each instance costs around 100 USD/month. It will be a lot of money, if we have to do this.

Is it possible to stop and restart the instance programmatically(or auto resume) without losing the notebooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the VM to save money. And start it when you need it.

You can imagine to perform a script to shut down automatically all the notebook every night. Like this, if a data scientist forget to shut down their VM, you do it for them.

Comment: Thanks guillaume, so we need to create one notebook instance for each data scientist

Comment: You have 1 notebook per instance. if each data scientist must have their own development environment, yes, you have to create 1 instance per data scientist. To save money, you can stop the instances automatically with a script and let the data scientist start the instance that they want to use.